# IdSMTP ( indy componants) SSL Not Available on smtp.live.com

Tags: delphi, ssl, smtp, indy

Since November 20, 2019 an exception is raised when sending an email to `smtp.live.com` for all users of my software.

`*ERROR: SSL is not available on this server*.` With other servers like Gmail, there is no problem.

My question is: How with Indy components use the right method of communication with the server `smtp.live.com`. Thank you. `Pascal`

Comment: Please show your actual setup of the Indy components. Are you connecting to a legacy SSL port, or a modern TLS port? Do you have `TIdSMTP.UseTLS` set to `utUseImplicitTLS` or `utUseExplicitTLS`? The error you are seeing implies `utUseExplicitTLS`, but the server is not advertising support for the `STARTTLS` command, or you have `TIdSMTP.UseEHLO` set to `false`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Rémy,

Delphi 2007,Indy 10
Server : **Smtp.Live.com** 
Port   :

I try with 
   587 port -> message  : SSL Available on this server 
             or Client was authentificated to send anonymous during MAIL FROM (if ehlo = False)
   465 port -> message  : connection Timed out

My source code

```
IdSMTP.IOHandler  := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.MMode := sslmUnassigned;
IdSMTP.UseTLS := utUseRequireTLS;
IdSMTP.AuthType := atDefault;
IdSMTP.UseEhlo := False;
```

ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll are old but compatible with delphi 2007 version.
Sorry for my bad english.
Pascal

Comment: This should have been posted an an edit to your original question instead of as an answer. In any case, don't use `utUseRequireTLS` on the client side, use `utUseExplicitTLS` instead. And `UseEhlo` needs to be True instead of False.

Comment: Thank's Rémy, I try It.